# rails subclass not found when trying to locate a specific phrase in a db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a page only show the results in a table that have the word `ford` inside the `type` column.

Heres what i have

Controller:

```
  def type
    @type = Brand.where(type: "ford")
  end
```

And in the view i have:

```
<% @type.each do |t| %>
```

This is currently returning this error
on the line above,

```
The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'ford'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Brand.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

Why am i getting this error and how do i go about fixing it?

Sam

*Edit*

```
@type = Brand.where(car_type: "ford")
```

Comment: You will have to rename the `type` column to something else because like `name`, because `type` is a reserved name used for Single Table Inheritance model.

Comment: what output are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is a reserved keyword in rails models.

You can refer all the reserved keywords [here](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words).

It will work, if you change the column name from `type` to something else

Comment: I did this, Which worked, However ford isnt showing. even though it exists in the table

Comment: Have Done :) Hope you can help !!